# CookiePolicyOptions interfering with localization cookie in Blazor server-side app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side and I have the following cookie policy options set up:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

The app also implements cookie localization as described in this [MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#dynamically-set-the-culture-by-user-preference).

However, the problem is that with the above policy options, the localization cookie is not being created.

If I change the policy options to (or remove them completely):

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
});
```

The localization cookie is created and localization works as expected. So the original options are interfering with the localization cookie.

A sample Blazor project experiencing this problem is found in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cryo75/CultureTest).

Is there a solution/workaround in which I have the original cookie policy options (required for consent) and also a working localization cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Two changes must be done do get it working:

Change the cooking policy options as follows:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});
```

Change the code where the culture is set as follows:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class CultureController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Set(string culture, string redirectUri)
    {
        if (culture != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
                    new RequestCulture(culture, culture)), 
                    new CookieOptions {
                        Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
                        IsEssential = true,
                        Path = "/",
                        HttpOnly = false,
                    }
            );
        }

        return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
    }
}
```

`IsEssential` is the most important property as it tells the cookie to bypass any cookie policy.